# How to validate if a foreign key entry exists?

Tags: jsf, jpa, jsf-2, jpa-2.0

I have foreign key inside my `Customer` table.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "DISCOUNT_CODE", referencedColumnName = "DISCOUNT_CODE")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private DiscountCode discountCode;
```

I have a form that contains all fields of this table (including the foreign key `discountCode` and its description from the other table).

I want to be able to show a message that this foreign key does not exist in case that the user entered an input that does not exist in the foreign key table.
When I onblur this field, then I'm retriving its description from the table. How can I show the error message of invalid field when the user onblurs it and it does not exist in the table?

Comment: As an alternative you can also just use a (autocomplete)dropdown field instead of a text field. At least, predefined values are supposed to be shown by a dropdown.

Comment: @BalusC: I have to many fields in this table, so i don't want to have a dropdown field taht would have more then 1000 records inside of it....

Comment: That's exactly why I suggested "autocomplete" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a `Validator`. It should look like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class DiscountCodeValidator implements Validator {
    @EJB
    private MrBean mrBean;

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        String discountCode = (String) value;

        if (!mrBean.checkDiscountCodeExistence(discountCode)) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("This code is not valid!"));
        }
    }
}
```

In your .xhtml file, you can declare this validator as following:

```
<h:inputText id="discountCode" value="#{someBean.discountCode}" 
             validator="#{discountCodeValidator}" 
             required="true" requiredMessage="Discount code is required.">
   <f:ajax event="blur" render="discountMsg" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="discountCode" id="discountMsg"/>
```

One thing to note is I assume that you would inject an EJB to check the existence of the discount code with the `checkDiscountCodeExistence()` function. Hence, I annotated the above Validator as a `@ManagedBean`. If you don't need to inject any EJBs, you can annotate the Validator with `@FacesValidator`.

Comment: thank's for your answer.. is there a way to this without the `Validator` ? can I do it in a fuction inside my managed or session bean? (so I won't have to define the `validator`). thank's again.

Comment: Of course you can. Suppose your ManagedBean is `mrBean`, you can put the `public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException` function directly inside that bean. After that, you only need to declare the validator with `validator="#{mrBean.validate}"`.

Comment: thank's it works great. I have another question regarding this issue, how can I set a defult message from a `.properties` file instead of writing `new FacesMessage("This code is not valid!")` like in your example? thank's.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I have never done that before. I guess you would need some function to read the whole .properties file whenever the application starts and put all the properties into some variables and then use it where you need to.

Comment: o.k , i will dig in to it.. another thing i forgot to ask. when my field value is unvalid i'm showing the message, I want also to set focus on this field so that the user wont be able to continue until he changes the field to a valid one. how can i do this? thank's again!

Comment: Unless you hide or disable all other fields, you cannot force him to not to move to other fields. If you want to focus on the field, you would need some client-side script.

Comment: o.k, but in my client-side script how can i know that the field returned as unvalid one? how will i be able to diff between a valid and an unvalid field?

Comment: :) haha good question. I have no idea too. Normally, with JSF's validation in place, a user will never be able to do anything until he submit correct infos. Hence, you don't really need to force him to focus on an invalid field.