# Inject managed-bean property into custom converter

Tags: list, jsf, properties, javabeans, converters

How can I inject a property of a managed-bean into a custom converter?

For instance, a generic List so that I can extract my object from the list inside the converter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In several case, when you need to inject a bean such as ManagedBean, EJB, etc. into a `Converter` or a `Validator`, you can try annotating your `Converter` or `Validator` as a ManagedBean. For example, you can try this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyConverter implements Converter {
    @EJB
    private MrEJBBean mrEJBBean;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{mrsManagedBean}")        
    private MrsManagedBean mrsManagedBean;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {        
        // Convert to object
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        // Convert to string
    }

}
```

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629550/how-to-validate-if-a-foreign-key-entry-exists/8629655#8629655) for an example on `Validator`.

Comment: +1 I would also note that the `Converter` must be referenced via a managed bean value binding expression and not via a registered converter ID.