# How can I inject in @FacesConverter?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I wrote a converter. I am using CDI and injection parallel. In that case the classes are not injected. How can I make the injection possible?

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = MyClass.class)

public class MyConverter implements Converter{

    @EJB
    private ClassForEJB classForEJB;

    @Inject
    private ClassForInject classForInject;

// Converter Methods
}
```

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675831/inject-managed-bean-property-into-custom-converter

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `@FacesConverter` isn't an eligible injection target. Replace it by `@ManagedBean` or `@Named`. As you'd like to use CDI as as well, use `@Named`.

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped // I assume that your converter doesn't have any state.
public class MyConverter implements Converter {
    // ...
}
```

You only need to change the way it's been referenced in the views. You cannot rely on `forClass` anymore. You'd need to explicitly specify it as `#{myConverter}`.

```html
<h:inputSomething ... converter="#{myConverter}" />
```

or

```html
<h:inputSomething ...>
    <f:converter binding="#{myConverter}" />
</h:inputSomething>
```

If you really need to keep the `@FacesConverter` in favor of `forClass`, then you'd need to grab the EJB manually by JNDI. A concrete example is shown in [this blog article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#GettingAnEJBInFacesConverterAndFacesValidator). I can however not tell that for CDI beans.

The JSF guys have confirmed this embarrassing oversight and they will make the `@FacesConverter` an eligible injection target in upcoming <strike>JSF 2.2, see also [JSF spec issue 763](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-763)</strike> JSF 2.3.

#### See also:

- [How to inject @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired, etc in @FacesConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665673/how-to-inject-ejb-persistencecontext-inject-autowired-etc-in-facesconve)

---

**Update** if you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), or are open to using it, since its version 1.6, when just having OmniFaces JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`, all `@FacesConverter`s (and `@FacesValidator`s) in your webapp [automatically](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesConverter) become eligible for CDI and EJB injection without any extra effort.

Comment: Is it a problem to have a converter without Facesconverter annotation? For performance or something else?

Comment: No. It just changes the way how it's been managed.

Comment: It works as expected from BalusC

Comment: Your answers always cleans and working.

Comment: "*The JSF guys have confirmed this embarrassing oversight and they will make the `@FacesConverter` an eligible injection target **in upcoming JSF 2.2***" Why is this not a fact in JSF 2.2 yet (even in the latest version JSF 2.2.8-02)?

Comment: @Tiny: it didn't made into JSF 2.2. They postponed it at the last moment to JSF 2.3 because it had an unexpected side effect which they couldn't fix in short time before official JSF 2.2 release. Again, OmniFaces to the rescue.

Comment: @BalusC Dumb question : You said ApplicationScoped, so the instance will be shared through all users. Won't that bring problems like delays and such? I mean is it a risk that should be considered ?

Comment: @Ced: Java is multithreaded.

Comment: Is there a difference between Omnifaces facesConverter and a `@Named` `@ApplicationScoped` annotated converter ? Dunno which one to pick.

Comment: @Ced: see duplicate for (dis)advantage.

Comment: There is nothing there. I guess it's just about the same anyway. I was just interested to know if omnifaces made those RequestScoped or if they were created once and reused. Oh maybe you meant the forClass.

Comment: It seems that it is not supported in JSF 2.3, I get a NPE. :(