# Does CDI @Inject in FacesConverter with CODI's @Advanced work with AJAX requests?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, cdi, myfaces, codi

We use `FacesConverter`s and annotate them with `CODI`'s `@Advanced` annotation in order to be able to use `CDI` injection. This works with normal requests. But on `AJAX` requests the injected `CDI` beans are null. And the `FacesContext` parameter in

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value)
```

is `org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImpl` instead of `org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.request.CodiFacesContextWrapper` as it is on normal requests when injection works.

Does anyone know how to make injection work in `FacesConverter`s with `AJAX` requests? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using MyFaces-Core or Mojarra as an JSF implementation?

Comment: Interesting. You said that it works for non-AJAX, but in my app (I'm recently migrating to CDI from JSF managed beans), @Advanced with FacesConverter(forClass=...) is not injecting the bean on non-AJAX.

Comment: FYI, see the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13156834/933054; that answer lead me to add JSF (RequestScoped) Managed Beans that only contain @FacesConverter and Converter. I tested it, and it works as I am migrating from JSF managed beans to CDI managed beans.