# Data already exist issue in JSF 2.1 using primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i need a little help from you. i have made StoreNameValidator in my project which checks and prompt user to re-enter store name if the entered store name already exists in the database. all the time it gives me null value. i have run it in the debug mode. i send you code. please help me. store object is null. help me please.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
@FacesValidator("com.kicsit.ehub.validator.StoreNameValidator")
public class StoreNameValidator implements Validator {
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{StoreService}")
    private IStoreService storeService;



    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object storeName)
            throws ValidatorException {
        Store store = null;
        try{
            **store** = getStoreService().getStoreByName(storeName.toString());
            if(store != null){
                FacesMessage msg = 
                        new FacesMessage("Store name Already Registered.", 
                                "Already Registered.");
                    msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                    throw new ValidatorException(msg);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }

    public IStoreService getStoreService() {
        return storeService;
    }

    public void setStoreService(IStoreService storeService) {
        this.storeService = storeService;
    }

}
```

and here i'm using this validator.

```
<p:inputText required="true" value="#{storeController.storeBean.storeName}" >
    <p:ajax event="blur" update="registerMsg" />
    **<f:validator validatorId="com.kicsit.ehub.validator.StoreNameValidator" />**
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: you currently cannot use managed property within validator or converter, you have too look it up yourself using `context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, elExpression, type)`. I think jsf 2.2 will support it.

Comment: @djmj can u please elaborate the answer?

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8677938/1530938 @Umair . You're getting the null because `IStoreService` wasn't injected (and that's because `FacesConverter` does not currently support injection. JSF2.2 promises to provide this. That's what djmj is saying effectively

Comment: You can retrieve instances manually using current context like:  `IStoreService storeService = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{StoreService}", IStoreService.class)` Use this fragment in your constructor or lazy in your conversion/validation method to initialize your instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method definition:

```
public void validate(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object brandName)
            throws ValidatorException {
        Brand brand = null;
        try{
            brand = brandService.getBrandByBrandName(brandName.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
        if(brand != null){
            tempBean.setBrandDescription(brand.getBrandDescription());
            tempBean.setBrandName(brand.getBrandName());
            tempBean.setBrandId(brand.getBrandId());
            FacesMessage msg = 
                    new FacesMessage("Already Exists", 
                            "Re-Enter Brand Name");
                msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }

    }
```

in the xhtml document. use it as:

```
<p:outputLabel for="brandNametxt" value="Brand Name :" />
                    <p:inputText validator="#{brandController.validate}" requiredMessage="Brand Name is Required" id="brandNametxt" required="true" value="#{brandController.bean.brandName}" >
                        <p:ajax event="blur" update="brandNametxt,err-msg,AlreadyExist,:selectedBrand" />
                    </p:inputText>
```