# Setting bean property from validator

Tags: jsf-2, validation

Is there a way to set a bean property from a `Validator`?
In my case, I have a `validator` which connects to the database and performs some validation.
Upon successful validation, I want to save the object received from database, inside a bean property.
Currently i'm doing this by setting a static property of my bean from the validator.
Here is my validator method

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    //perform validation
    if(isValidated) {
        Referral ref = database.getReferral(value.toString());  //receive referral object from batabase
        RegistrationBean.staticReferral = ref; // Set ref to RegistrationBean's static property
    } else {
       FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "Invalid Referral!", "Referral does not exist!");
        throw new ValidatorException(msg);
    }
}
```

and here is my `RegistrationBean`

```
@ManagedBean  
@ViewScoped  
public class RegistrationBean implements Serializable {

    //other bean properties
    private Referral referral;
    public static Referral staticReferral;

    public RegistrationBean() {
        //default constructor
    }

    public Referral getReferral() {
        this.staticReferral = referral;
        return referral;
    }
    // other getters, setters and methods
}
```

So the questions in my mind are:

- Is there a way to set a bean property directly from a bean? (without
  using a static property)
- Would there be any concurrency issues (one user may receive other user's selected referral object etc) using the existing approach?

Thanks

Comment: Static members in managed beans are shared among all instances (and users of your application). So think at least twice before making a member variable static.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MattHandy. 
So how to set the bean property from validator without using a static property?

Comment: If you make your validator a managed bean, you can inject your target managed bean into your validator. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8629655/620338) for details. (In the example an EJB is injected, but you can inject a JSF managed bean via the `@ManagedProperty` annotation).

Comment: Thanks alot @MattHandy! :) 
This has indeed solved my problem! :)
Thanks again!

Comment: Good to hear. So I will add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static members in managed beans are shared among all instances (and users of your application). So think at least twice before making a member variable static.

If you make your validator a managed bean, you can inject your target managed bean into your validator. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8629655/620338) for details.

In the given example an EJB is injected, but you can inject a JSF managed bean via the `@ManagedProperty` annotation